# Python beginner has some problems with the spotipy search function

Tags: python-3.x, spotipy

i am trying to set up a basic tool which is supposed to do following:
1. Search for Musicans in Spotify 
2. Print results in a way i can use them for stuff (e.g. show output in a window or something like that)

Unfortunatly i cant wrap my head around following Problem:

```
import spotipy
import sys
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials


client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='',
                                                           client_secret='')


spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)


result = spotify.search(q='Korn', limit=5)

for i, t in enumerate(result['tracks']['items']):     # way i dont understand
        print (' ', i, t['name'])


print(result)       #way i would like to do it
```

The code can print a list in this enumerate fashion but isnt capable of printing it normally. The thing is I dont understand the way enumerate does this. 
Can someone please give me some insights how the search function and enumerate work and maybe show me an elegant solution so i can print this list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the spotipy module so I'll have to assume a few things, based on what you said works or doesn't work.

So... your variable named 'result' seems to behave like a dictionary. You can index it with keys ('tracks', 'items'), (as shown there: `result['tracks']['items']`), and this seems to give you back stuff that behaves like a list containing stuff that behaves like a dictionary, that among other things contains the key 'name' (as shown there: `t['name']`).

To illustrate how `enumerate` works, here's an example:

```py
>>> hello = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> print(list(enumerate(hello)))
[(0, 'h'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'l'), (3, 'l'), (4, 'o')]
```

It essentially gives you back tuples of each index in the list, and what is at that index.

Also note that Python has a principle called 'duck-typing'. It says that “If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck.”. That's why I don't worry to much about what type an object is, what I care about is what it behaves like.

Now, when you say something like:

```py
for index, element in enumerate(elements):
```

You're using what's called unpacking. It lets you separate the tuples that `enumerate` gives you into two variables.

Then if we wanted to simply do `print(result)`, the class that let you instantiate result would need to implement either the `__repr__` or `__str__` methods. In it, you would have all the logic that's contained in your for loop, grabbing the data at the appropriate keys in the dictionary-like object and returning a correctly formatted string. But it looks like this class comes from an external library, so I'm not sure it would be a good idea to implement these yourself (I don't have experience doing that yet).

Hope that my explanations were at least a little bit helpful.